# How to update and share big statefull tables based on event stream?

Tags: apache-kafka, rabbitmq, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, spark-streaming, delta-lake

Say I have a stream of deposits, withdraws and cancelations. coming in jason over rabbit mq. millions of transactions per minute.

I want to mantain two tables, one for transsctions and one for table with each customers balance. e. g.

```
transactions
| date | customer | opetation | amount | canceled |
|1/1/01| alice    | deposit   | 10     | no       |
|1/1/01| alice    | deposit   | 2      | yes      |
|1/1/01| bob      | deposit   | 20     | no       |
|2/1/01| alice    | withdraw  | 5      | no       |
|2/1/01| bob      | deposit   | 2      | no       |
|2/1/01| bob      | withdraw  | 5      | no       |

balance
| customer | balance |
| alice    | 5       |
| bob      | 17      |
```

the transaction table is well over 500gb, excluding indexes.

however, I would like to be able to massively share these tables, to a point that relational databases starts getting costly to scale.

can consider I would be the only one *writting into the table*, but the only control over who is reading is whatever interface I make available to the clients (e.g. jdbc, api, topic, etc.).

logging the transactions is easy enough using something like `kinesis firehose`, though what would be the possibles or even recomended architectures for mantaining the stateful tables `transactions` and `balance`?

Merge using `deltalake` or `snowflake`? Ive been suggested `Cassandra`.

How do yoy keep the these tables updated based on events instead of doing batch cycles?

Comment: Does the balance table need to be real time or is it acceptable to have time late, say once every 15 minutes to update balances? Both are possible with Snowflake, but the tolerance for latency affects choice of approach.

Comment: some tolerance is acceptable.